# using a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having trouble with this script recognizing my variable as a variable. The important part of the script is as follows:

```
    var content = 'imagereims';
    var ms = content.substring(5);
    $.get("../msimages/image.php", {ms: 'ms', pid: '<?php echo "$pid" ?>'}
    );
```

I want the script to recognize the variable `ms` as `reims`, but when the page displays it doesn't recognize the content of the variable. It just repeats `ms`. I've tried writing the variable without single quotes and with double quotes. I get the same result.

Any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you would do:

```
var content = 'imagesreims'
var ms = content.substring(6);
$.get("../msimages/image.php", {ms: ms, pid: '<?php echo "$pid" ?>'}
```

Note two things:

1. use `ms` as the variable, rather than the literal 'ms'
2. correct index 4 to 6, if you want `reims`

Comment: Perfect -- those were my two problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to leave off the quotes on 'ms'. Try this:

```
var content = 'imagesreims'
var ms = content.substring(4);
$.get("../msimages/image.php", {ms: ms, pid: '<?php echo "$pid" ?>'});
```

'ms' is saying use this string literal as the value.

You'll also want a different substring. Try `content.substring(6)`. `content.substring(4)` will yield 'esreims'.

As mentioned in another answer, you missed the `);` at the end, which I've included in my answer.

Comment: Well that was my initial thought; but no dice. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the substring and the variable's empty.

Comment: The substring looks correct, but it won't give you what you are expecting. Like I mentioned, use a different substring.  The code I gave seems to work (assuming your PHP code works correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Current your line:

```
var ms = content.substring(4);
```

is assigning `ms` the value `esreims`. See documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

All of these answers have pointed out errors in the code. You'll want to draw from them all.